# TableRowSorter results in row numbers being disorganized

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, tablerowsorter

It is important for my program that the row number assigned to the variable within is consistent with its position, but after sorting this gets messed up. Using DefaultTableModel, this is what I use to sort:

```
int rownumber = Table.getRowCount();

TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(Table.getModel());

Table.setRowSorter(sorter);

List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>(rownumber);

sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(1, SortOrder.ASCENDING));

sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
```

The sort is done after pressing a JButton and works as intended visually on the JTable, but the problem is that in reality, the first entry will always be in the position (1,1), seeing as my JTable has two columns. For example, if my table looked like this:

```
|----|----|
|Col1|Col2|
|----|----|
|  1 |  2 |
|----|----|
|  3 |  4 |
|----|----|
```

Even though the top row has the values ( 1, 2 ), reading from `model.getValueAt(0,1)` would return the value 4, as that was the row put in first. I hope this is clear; thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `TableRowSorter` does NOT modify the original model.  It creates a proxy around the original model and maps the row indices between the view and the model. When accessing the model, you need to convert the row index from the view to the model (and visa-versa). Start by looking at [`JTable#convertRowIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int))

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm afraid I'm a total newbie, so I just need some clarification as to where I would place this method; after the sort or elsewhere when I need to use `model.getValueAt()` ?  I'm also lost on what to put in the `(int index)` half of the method. If you would be so kind as to provide a brief example code I would much appreciate it. :)

Comment: The question is, in what context do you get the row value?  If you get the row value from the view context and want to get the value in the model, then you need to use `convertRowIndexToModel` and pass the result through `getValueAt`.  If you have the model index and want to get the view index, then you need to use `convertRowIndexToView`

Comment: Basically, if you look at the table in my original question, I want to get the correct values from `model.getValueAt()` . This is how I put values into the table, if it's any help:

Comment: `row[0] = Name; Row[1] = Together; model.addRow(row);`

Comment: Then, I would assume, you want to use `table.getVaueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(0), 0)`, this will give you the row which appears first in the table

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using `model.getValueAt()` was the problem. Switching to simply `Table.getValueAt()` resolved the issue.